# Legendary chest appearance

Tags: clash-royale

Are there any limitations to when legendary chests start to appear in the deals section? Do you have to reach any specific level / arena to be able to buy one?

Also, is loot totally random or also limited to your current arena?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the loot chests are on a very large rotation, and winning matches with full chest slots will not advance this rotation, so doing matches with full chest slots will not cause you to lose a rare chest. And you can get a legendary chest in any arena,with the legendary card being completely random.

Second, legendary chest appear in the shop for 500 gems after arena 7. Also, the arena 10 pack includes a legendary chest, and is $9.99. With a slight chance of one appearing randomly for $9.99 anytime.